# Merge [atomic] and [atomicity], and do it atomically

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

We have tags [atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomic) with 2781 questions and [atomicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomicity) with 574.  They are both about the same thing: operations which are indivisible, and which either succeed completely or fail with no effect.

I suggest that [atomicity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomicity) be made a synonym of [atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomic), and that this be done in an indivisible fashion, which hopefully will succeed completely instead of failing with no effect.

Comment: Or even: *Atomically merge [atomicity] into [atomic]*

Comment: What an atomic bomb of a pun

Comment: Come on, the verb should really be _fuse_, not _merge_.  If the _fusion_ doesn't catch on, a later _fission_ would always be possible.

Comment: Is there _an atomical_ tag ? That would bring up the things to another level, merge atomically two things in one.

Comment: Odd: I'm getting "Nate Eldredge is a new contributor ...".

Comment: Good thing we aren't going to nuke the tag!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm: New to Meta.SO, yes - I guess I haven't had occasion to post here before.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like it could be useful to have one tag for CPU-level hardware atomicity (load / store / RMW / transactional-memory), and another for higher-level atomicity of database or filesystem operations.

When I'm tagging, I sometimes look at the descriptions to remind myself of the fact that these tags unfortunately *don't* seem to be trying to distinguish themselves that way.  [atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/atomic) mentions databases and filesystems, but *also* mentions "low-level accesses in multithreaded programs".

I haven't looked at usage patterns, to see if one is tag or the other is used more heavily in combination with database tags, or with any other tag.  Synonymizing doesn't destroy the historical information of which was tagged what (until the next edit), so we shouldn't delay that over possible future plans to put more effort into more specific tags for these different contexts.

I proposed the synonym on https://stackoverflow.com/tags/atomic/synonyms, your suggestion seems reasonable to me.

---

Also note, many C++ questions with either of these tags should probably use [stdatomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stdatomic) *instead*, not as well.